# Connect extremal points of contour lines

Tags: matlab, max, contour

I'm trying to mark and connect the maximum points in a contour plot in matlab.

If I take this simple example:

```
x = -2:0.2:2;
y = -2:0.2:3;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = X.*exp(-X.^2-Y.^2);
contour(X,Y,Z,'ShowText','on')
```

It gives the contour curves bellow, and the black line and red circles is what I would like to plot.

[image: contour plot with max points]

I've tried searching for the indices of maximum values for each row in Z, then plotting the corresponding X and Y values. 
This didn't give me the correct values in my original problem.

What I'm looking for is whether there is a way to extract these values from the figure/data automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data for the contour lines can be extracted from the call to [`contour`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html). The first returned value is the [contour matrix](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html#mw_6bc1813f-47cf-4c44-a454-f937ea210ab6) which can be parsed to give you the points of every every contour line. Then it's just a matter of logistics to find the "maximum" point, which you really seem to mean the point along the contour with largest `y` value:

```
x = -2:0.2:2;
y = -2:0.2:3;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = X.*exp(-X.^2-Y.^2);
M = contour(X,Y,Z,'ShowText','on');

inow = 1;
maxpoints = [];
while inow < size(M,2)
   % column at inow contains level value and number of points in contour line
   level = M(1,inow);
   nvals = M(2,inow);
   % extract coordinates of the corresponding contour line
   xvals = M(1,inow+1:inow+nvals);
   yvals = M(2,inow+1:inow+nvals);

   % find max y value along the contour
   [ymax, ind] = max(yvals);
   xmax = xvals(ind);
   maxpoints(end+1,:) = [xmax, ymax];

   % increment index
   inow = inow + nvals + 1;
end

% filter points as necessary
inds = maxpoints(:,1) > 0; % contours to the right
keeppoints = maxpoints(inds,:);

% plot them
hold on;
plot(keeppoints(:,1),keeppoints(:,2),'o-');
```

The `maxpoints` array we constructed has size `[ncontours, 2]` and contains the coordinates of the "maximum" points. You need to filter these if you only want to work with some of the visible contours. Here's the result:

[image: resulting figure with "maximum" line plotted]

As you can see, the precision of the line is only as good as the precision of the contour lines themselves. You can increase the accuracy by making your data more dense and consequently your contour lines smoother. The above with `0.02` step instead of `0.2` in the `meshgrid` call:

[image: result with nice and smooth resolution]